# How can we use Google Cloud Tasks as a separate service to enqueue jobs and functions from other microservices?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, queue, backgroundworker, google-cloud-tasks

I have been recently looking into Google Cloud Tasks and its usage for enqueuing tasks. However, as far as I understood, it seems that we can only run the jobs in the background if they are running on Google Cloud App Engine.

I am trying to use Google Cloud Tasks in different microservices that are deployed using Kubernetes and are not on Google Cloud App Engine. So, most of the examples that I was looking at are putting the result of the task into the queue which is not what I am looking for.

I want to leave a task (from within my microservice) for the worker, that seems is on the Google Cloud App Engine, to run and not block the microservice. Is there any way that I can do that?

[The sample code that Google provides](https://github.com/googleapis/python-tasks/blob/main/samples/snippets/create_http_task.py#L64), puts the result of the task inside the payload which is not the case for me because due to the nature of my task, it will take some time and I want to run it as a background job, not block the code inside my microservice which is deployed on a Kubernetes cluster.

To recap:

- I have a time-consuming task in my `microservice1` (let's say processing some data or sending emails)
- When hitting an endpoint in my `microservice1`, I will trigger the time-consuming task of processing the data or sending emails
- I want to put this task as a background job to the queue of Google Cloud Tasks which is running in the Google Cloud App Engine

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Cloud Tasks is a managed execution flow as opposed to an unmanaged execution in the background.

The issue is that Cloud Tasks requires AppEngine and also results in the work unit being enqueued.

This is by design as the AppEngine component manages the explicit invocations (executions) of each item enqueued and guarantees that it is processed.
This means that the AppEngine component continuously monitors the task execution and will attempt to execute the request across the resources available until it is completed successfully.

If you are looking for a true async execution where the request is running in the background and execution flow is free to progress without active checks, a Pub/Sub solution is recommended as this allows the execution to be triggered and will run however long it needs to using either explicit or implicit resources.
The success/failure of the Pub/Sub execution would then be the responsibility of the OP to manage in their solution.

You can also refer to this [link](https://joncloudgeek.com/blog/managing-background-jobs-with-cloud-tasks/) for more details.